# Problem with inflating xml-Layout on custom layout class

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-custom-view

I have a custom ConstraintLayout class (Card.java) which overrides the `onDraw()` method to draw a hexagon in his background. On the foreground i try to have three `TextViews` to display three numbers.
For this I inflate a `card.xml` in the constructor of Card. The TextViews are displayed, but not at the right position. They should match the width and height of the Card and then position itself to the top-left and top-right corner and one to the bottom of the Card. But they do something like shrink itself and go to the top-left corner.

I have tried to change the root element of card.xml to "`merge`" instead of "...`ConstraintLayout`" but this doesn't change anything.

I also tried to use Guidelines to position the TextViews relative to its width. I try to prevent the use of fixed margins, so the Text is always at the right place, also when the size of the Card changes.

Card.java:

```
public class Card extends ConstraintLayout {

    private int mSize;
    private Path mHexagon;
    private Paint mPaintHexagon;
    private TextView mT1, mT2, mT3;

    public Card(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        inflate(context, R.layout.card, this);
        // Numbers
        mT1 = findViewById(R.id.num1);
        mT2 = findViewById(R.id.num2);
        mT3 = findViewById(R.id.num3);

        // Hexagon
        mSize = Field.getHexSize(); // Size is used to calculate the 
        setPath();
        mPaintHexagon = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        mPaintHexagon.setColor(0x50888888);
        mPaintHexagon.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        canvas.drawPath(mHexagon, mPaintHexagon);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
        int width = 2 * mSize;
        int height = (int) (Math.sqrt(3) * mSize);
        Log.d(TAG, "Measure w:" + width + " h:" + height);
        setMeasuredDimension(width, height);
    }
}
```

card.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

<TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/num2"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
        android:text="2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"/>

<TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/num1"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
        android:text="1"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/num2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/num3"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>

<TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/num3"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
        android:text="3"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:background="@color/colorAccentDark"
    android:padding="5dp">

<de.portugall.markus.takeiteasy.Card
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        android:id="@+id/card"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

[Screenshot Card in Layout-Debug mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RCLqF.jpg)

Comment: @MikeM. As I described above I already tried to use `<merge>` instead of `<ConstraintLayout>`. I added a Picture where you can see how the Card looks like when `<merge>` is used.

Comment: You don't say how `Card.java` is added to the layout. If you are programmatically adding the card into a `ConstraintLayout` are you setting its constraints? If you don't, everything will collapse to (0,0). Post more information about how `Card.java` is added to the view hierarchy for additional help.

Comment: Oops, sorry, I missed that part. Well, you definitely want `<merge>` tags there, 'cause otherwise you end up with an extra nested `ConstraintLayout`. Beyond that, I don't use `ConstraintLayout`, so I'm not sure I can help much further. Sorry about that. I would say, though, that `ConstraintLayout` might be a little overkill for such a relatively simple layout. If you don't absolutely need that to be a `ConstraintLayout`, you might consider trying a more straightforward `ViewGroup`, like `RelativeLayout`. Cheticamp makes a good point, too.

Comment: @MikeM. I used ConstraintLayout because i can use percentage margins there with the help of Guidelines. If I could make a RelativeLayout with percentage margins i would use it, but I read that ConstrainLayout would be better if you need something like that.

Comment: @Cheticamp I edited the post so you can see my `activity_main.xml` which is just normally added to the `MainAcivity`. So the `Card` is just added in xml.
I just played a bit with its constraints and I noticed, that when I set it to `0dp`, the complete layout will match its parents, and also the `TextView`s are displayed in the right corners. But i wonder why the Text is more wrapping than the Hexagon in the background when I set the constraints to `wrap_content`

Comment: `card.xml` is `match_parent` but its parent is `wrap_content`. How big should the card be? There are also constraint issues, but they can't be answer until the card size answer is know.

Comment: @Cheticamp isn't the size of the `Card` set in its `onMeasure()`? The Card should get the size which is calculated in the `onMeasure` method and the `card.xml` should take the same size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'onMeasure()` has some [rules](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/how-android-draws) that you are not strictly following. I have seen these rules broken with impunity, but I think that you are being caught, but we will push on.

In `onMeasure()` you are setting the height and width of the custom layout but `ConstraintLayout` still understands the layout as `wrap_content`. You will need to set the layout params to the new height and width. Add the following code to the end of `onMeasure()`:

```
// Although we have measured the layout, we need to tell ConstraintLayout in the
// LayoutParams that the size is not longer "wrap_content".
ViewGroup.LayoutParams lp = getLayoutParams();
lp.width = width;
lp.height = height;
setLayoutParams(lp);
```

The second issue that you have is that you are adding a `ConstraintLayout` (card.xml) to a `ConstraintLayout` (your custom layout), but you are not setting the constraints. In the constructor for `Card.java`, add the following to set the constraints:

```
ConstraintLayout layout = (ConstraintLayout) inflate(context, R.layout.card, this);

// We have added R.layout.card to a ConstraintLayout (this custom layout), so we need
// to make sure that it is constrained properly.
ConstraintSet cs = new ConstraintSet();
cs.clone(layout);
cs.connect(R.id.layout, ConstraintSet.START, ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID, ConstraintSet.START);
cs.connect(R.id.layout, ConstraintSet.TOP, ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID, ConstraintSet.TOP);
cs.connect(R.id.layout, ConstraintSet.END, ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID, ConstraintSet.END);
cs.connect(R.id.layout, ConstraintSet.BOTTOM, ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID, ConstraintSet.BOTTOM);
cs.applyTo(layout);
```

You will need to change the height and width of the layout in `card.xml` to `0dp`. `match_parent` is never appropriate in `ConstraintLayout`.

This is a pictorial description of what is happening:

[image]

On a related note, you should consider [using the merge facility](https://trickyandroid.com/protip-inflating-layout-for-your-custom-view/) to avoid nested `ConstraintLayouts` as other have mentioned.

Comment: that sounds really helpful. I will try it later :) Thank you!

Comment: okay the first part of it fixed it! Just needed to edit the `LayoutParams` in `onMeasure()`. The second thing wasn't needed because I used `merge` instead of `ConstraintLayout` in the `card.xml`.